# Help identify schematic symbol

Tags: inductor, surge-protection, ferrite-bead, lightning

Is it a ferrite bead or coil of some sort?
Or is it a gas discharge tube? Usually though it has a different symbol.

If it is a ferrite bead then what is the point of those chassis connectors?

Could anyone point to an example part no.

The schematic is an input connector for a MIL rated device and is probably for noise or voltage spike suppression.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it's a [feedthrough capacitor](https://www.utmel.com/blog/categories/capacitors/what-is-feedthrough-capacitor). From the linked site, this image may approximate what you are seeing there:

[image]

You can see the use of a wire through the center of a capacitor to illustrate that they are using a feedthrough cap.

Comment: Looks like a coaxial "pi filter". We used some stupidly expensive ones to keep EMI out of our SQUIDs. There are two physical disk capacitors and an inductor inside a hermetic (in that case) package that bolts through the housing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Do you think I may be right about a 'feedthrough?' Or are you thinking something else? (I need to look up 'coaxial pi' before I can be sure, as I don't have any experience with SQUIDs, so I figure I'll just ask.)

Comment: Yes, like a feedthrough capacitor but it has three parts inside it (and because the caps are disk types (that fill the internal diameter of the housing) and the mounting is feedthrough the attenuation is good over a really large bandwidth). They bolt into a bulkhead. Might be ones like feedthrough capacitors that solder into a hole in the bulkhead. Also there might be other variations on the name. I don't think you can make ones that good with regular discrete components very easily.

Comment: [here](https://www.apitech.com/globalassets/documents/products/emi-filters-components-magnetics/coaxial-filters--interconnects/low-pass-emi-filters1018.pdf) are some solder-in types.

Comment: Might not be feedthrough. There are other geometries available, e.g. https://www.ctscorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/4700-006.pdf